# port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, ssh

When I try to establish a connection to my server using ssh I get the message:

> ssh: connect to host 'domain name' port 22: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable.

I've tried changing the port value, but it didn't work. This happened after I performed an update to Ubuntu 16.04, after hitting restart I haven't been able to reconnect to the server.